# Capture image from device camera on Android webview

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

I need to capture image from the device camera from an html in the Android webview. I tried having an input tag with the capture attribute set but it also gives me the option to select the file instead of just the camera.

If I run the same app on a browser, it opens the camera immediately. This works fine on iOS webview but gives me option to select a file in Android webview.

Is there any way to block the user from using the file select and only open up the camera?